# data not enter in to foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having trouble with modifying a php application to have pagination. My error seems to be with my logic, and I am not clear exactly what I am doing incorrectly. I have had before, but am not currently getting errors that mysql_num_rows() not valid result resource and that invalid arguments were supplied to foreach. I think there is a problem in my logic which is stopping the results from mysql from being returned.

All my "test" echos are output except testing while loop. A page is generated with the name of the query and the word auctions, and first and previous links, but not the next and last links. I would be grateful if a more efficient way of generating links for the rows in my table could be pointed out, instead of making a link per cell. Is it possible to have a continuous link for several items?

```
if(domain_exists($email))  {

  $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);

  if (is_array($values) || is_object($values)) {
     foreach ($data as $key1) {

        $host = $key1['host'];
        $target = $key1['target'];
        $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);

     }
   }

}
```

Comment: are you sure $values is different variable ?

Comment: sorry not $values is there $ data instead of $values

Comment: May be $data is blank array. Please make sure $data has value or not

Comment: all code like this

Comment: function domain_exists($email) {
   
   $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
   
   $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX); 
   
   if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
   return $arr[0]['target'];
   }
   } 
     
   
   if(domain_exists($email))  {
   
   $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
   
   if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
   foreach ($data as $key1) {
   
    $host = $key1['host'];
    $target = $key1['target'];
    $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);
    
   }
   }

Comment: there values  are in $arr but not transfer into $data .......why happen like this ..?

Comment: function domain_exists($email)
   {
       $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
       $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
       if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
           return $arr[0]['target'];
       }
   }

Comment: if(domain_exists($email)){
       $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
       $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
       if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
           foreach ($data as $key1) {
               $host = $key1['host'];
               $target = $key1['target'];
               $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);
           }
       }
    
   if($data) {
     $status = "email id is valid";      
    } else {
     $status = "max record not exist";
    } 
          
   } else {
     $status = "not in syntax" ;
   }

Comment: its work but there is no mx record find so status value will be 'max record not exist' but there is status value is not syntax........ if there is no mx recored find status value will be 'max record not find but' the values are not in syntax......syntax error will be come on those cases there are email not in formate

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to set value for '$domain' varianble. So the value of this variable is NULL for this line '$data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);'

```
function domain_exists($email)
{
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
    $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
    if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
        return $arr[0]['target'];
    }
}
if(domain_exists($email)) {
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
    $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key1) {
            $host = $key1['host'];
            $target = $key1['target'];
            $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);
        }
    }
}
```